# Improve performance of the query

Tags: sql, sql-server

My query is taking very long time.

```
select distinct JobName,
       ValidationType,
       AppName,
       Result,
       ResultType,
       ErrorWarningDetails,
       CvtStartDateTime 
  from contentvalidationjobdetails with (nolock)
 where appname=@AppName 
       and result=@Result 
       and (cast(cvtstartdatetime as date) > @Date )
       and concat(Jobname,validationtype) not in (
                  select concat(jobname,validationtype) 
                    from Contentvalidationjobdetails with (nolock) 
                   where appname = @AppName 
                         and CVTStartDateTime = (
                          select top 1 teststartdatetime 
                            from contentvalidation 
                           where appname=@AppName 
                                 and Teststartdatetime<@Date
                        order by teststartdatetime desc
                         )
           )
```

I know that the concat(jobname,validationtype) is taking time. how to handle this.

Comment: I want to find the new jobname for the selected date and dates greater than that. I am concatenating jobname and validationtype because then they form the unique value

Comment: did you try to show the execution plan?

Comment: @Alexander because we try not to be snarky to newcomers and help them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place the query in FROm section to be executed just once (not for each line in WHERE). Add outer join and leave only records which has no joins.

```
select distinct JobName,
       ValidationType,
       AppName,
       Result,
       ResultType,
       ErrorWarningDetails,
       CvtStartDateTime 
  from contentvalidationjobdetails with (nolock)
       LEFT OUTER JOIN (
                  select concat(jobname,validationtype) cnt
                    from Contentvalidationjobdetails with (nolock) 
                   where appname = @AppName 
                         and CVTStartDateTime = (
                          select top 1 teststartdatetime 
                            from contentvalidation 
                           where appname=@AppName 
                                 and Teststartdatetime<@Date
                        order by teststartdatetime desc) sub ON concat(Jobname,validationtype)=sub.cnt

 where appname=@AppName 
       and result=@Result 
       and (cast(cvtstartdatetime as date) > @Date ))
  HAVING sub.cnt is null
```